# Vibrate Phone in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to use the vibration on the device (Windows Phone), however I can't seem to find the appropriate API to achieve this for Windows 10. In Windows 8.x, I can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206994(v=vs.105).aspx), however this is no longer available in Universal Windows Platform.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.devices.notification.vibrationdevice.vibrate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Jan 2016, you:

Right-click References in your Solution, Add Reference->Extensions->Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP

Then you can

`using Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification;`

and actually use it by:

`Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification.VibrationDevice v = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
v.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));`

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a background task when an app is suspended?

Comment: background tasks cannot vibrate, use a toast instead.

Answer (score 2):

Posted as a comment several minutes ago and now I'm confident this is what you need:

Use the `Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification.VibrationDevice` class and the `Vibrate` method it contains.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.devices.notification.vibrationdevice.vibrate

Answer (score 0):

check this, might help you. and the link you are using may be using a different api. anotehr thing I found on Microsoft documentation is that you cannot trust it, keep that in mind
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.phone.devices.notification.vibrationdevice.vibrate

Comment: Just so we're clear - you say Microsoft's documentation cannot be trusted, and then you go on to link to MSDN saying it might help?

Comment: Yes. Cannot be trusted as in don't trust its described behavior. Still the methods exist and might just work for his case.