# Is there a vibration api for UWP?

Tags: uwp, vibration

I'm currently merging an existing WP8.0 and Windows 8.1 app into a single new UWP app and was wondering where the equivalent to Silverlight's VibrateController can be found. I expected to find a similar API that was at least available to the Mobile device family.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vibrate Phone in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502601/vibrate-phone-in-uwp).

Comment: Did you see this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/626dbb11-3bde-4b07-b0f0-48493927a9b0/uwpis-there-a-vibration-api-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, see this '[How to vibrate a Windows Phone device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611853.aspx)'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification` namespace in uwp.

```
using Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification;

public void Vibrate()
{
    var device = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
    device.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
}
```